# How to present a distribution of one variable by 2 other variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hellow,
I want to show a distribution of a numeric variable `pain60heat` only for women `gendermale==2` that have had pain for 3 months `pain3month==1`.
I tried to write:

```
plot(sample.data$pain60heat~sample.data$gendermale1=="2"[sample.data$pain3month=="1"])
```

but I get an error:

> In sample.data$gendermale1 == "2"[sample.data$pain3month == "1"] :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? or what I should have written?

Thank you,
Maya

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would be great, but this is precisely something the tidyverse is great for! The problem isn't really with the plot, but with getting the data in the right form before we plot it.

Let's try and make some synthetic data:

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  pain60heat = rnorm(10000),
  gendermale = sample(1:2, 10000, replace = TRUE),
  pain3month = sample(0:1, 10000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

This looks to be a fair representation of what you put in your question.

Then we can do what you want using the `dplyr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse` set of packages (same as `ggplot2`).

So let's load the tidyverse and use `dplyr` to get the data we want:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  filter(gendermale == 2, pain3month == 1)
```

This `filter` function will take the data that has been piped into it (the `%>%` symbol) and only keep the observations that have a `gendermale` value of 2 and `painmonth` value of 3. We can then pipe this straight into `ggplot` to get a histogram of the distribution of `pain60heat`.

```
data %>%
  filter(gendermale == 2, pain3month == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pain60heat)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

You can then do all the beautifying of the plot you like, but the basic code above will give you something like this:

[image: Example Plot]

Hope this answers your question with respect to the `ggplot2` tag, for more information read [this book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), especially Chapters 3 and 5.

**EDIT/EXTENSION**

Rather than just plotting by one variable it is fairly easy to plot all combinations of the variables using the `facet_grid` function. Take a look:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pain60heat)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(gendermale ~ pain3month)
```

[image: Example 2]